# Permutations: Possibility of a permutation to be obtained from a given sequence

Tags: algorithm, sequence, permutation

Let us say that we are given a sequence of numbers `<P1, P2, P3, ... Pn>`. Now, we are allowed to perform a cyclic right shift on a certain continuous sub-sequence of length `k (<=n)`. If we can perform as many number of operations as described above, can we, at any point, obtain the following permutation:
`<P2, P1, P3, ... Pn>` (Note that the first two numbers are swapped)?

More specifically, for what possible values of `k` can the first two numbers be swapped?

PS: I know the answer, but I am in need of a concise proof! I am intentionally not providing the answer as it might thwart the delineation of the proof (I may be completely wrong in this regard, in which case, just ask me, in the comments, to provide the answer).

Comment: I find this type of question interesting, but given the focus on proof it's better suited to the CS SE site, or possibly the Maths SE.

Comment: Is `k` fixed once and for all ?

Comment: @fjardon: My interpretation is that not only k, but in fact *a specific subsequence* of length k is fixed...  Which obviously makes the question trivial.  OP needs to clarify.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Had _a specific subsequence_ of length k been fixed, the question would have been rendered moot! So, obviously, we are free to choose any continuous subsequence of length 'k'.

Comment: @Sankalp: Right, but the phrase "a certain continuous sub-sequence of length k" implies that the subsequence is indeed fixed.  You should instead use something like "Now, we are given a number k, and we are allowed to perform a cyclic right shift on any continuous subsequence of length k".